# kivy remove_widget not removing

Tags: button, kivy

I'm learning about kivy and was playing around with the PONG example. I added a button that appears after a player reaches a given score.

```
    if self.player2.score ==2 or self.player1.score==2:
        self.serve_ball(vel=(0, 0))
        self.btn= Button()
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
```

It binds to a function callback that resets the score and messages but I've tried several things to remove the button after pressed with no success.

```
def callback(self, instance):
    self.player2.score=0
    self.player1.score=0
    self.message1=""
    self.message2=""
    self.serve_ball(vel=(4,0))
    self.remove_widget(self.btn)
```

Any ideas how? Thanks, this is the complete code

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint


class PongPaddle(Widget):
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def bounce_ball(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            vx, vy = ball.velocity
            offset = (ball.center_y - self.center_y) / (self.height / 2)
            bounced = Vector(-1 * vx, vy)
            vel = bounced * 1.1
            ball.velocity = vel.x, vel.y + offset


class PongBall(Widget):

    #Vel of ball in x & y axis
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)

    #referencia para usar como vector
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x,velocity_y)

    #funcion move  1 paso en intervalos para animar la bola
    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None) 
    message2 = StringProperty("")
    message1 = StringProperty("")



    def callback(self, instance):
        self.player2.score=0
        self.player1.score=0
        self.message1=""
        self.message2=""
        self.serve_ball(vel=(4,0))
        self.remove_widget(self.btn)

    def serve_ball(self, vel=(4,0)):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = vel

    def btnn(self, instance):
        self.remove_widget(self.btn)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

        #bounce of paddles
        self.player1.bounce_ball(self.ball)
        self.player2.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        #bounce ball off bottom or top
        if (self.ball.y < self.y) or (self.ball.top > self.top):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

         #went of to a side to score point?
        if self.ball.x < self.x:
            self.player2.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(4, 0))
        if self.ball.x > self.width:
            self.player1.score += 1
            self.serve_ball(vel=(-4, 0))

        #emilio code
        if self.player2.score ==2 or self.player1.score==2:
            self.serve_ball(vel=(0, 0))
            self.btn= Button()
            self.add_widget(self.btn)
            self.btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)

            if self.player2.score == 2:
                self.message2= "player2 won!"


            if self.player1.score == 2:
                self.message1= "player1 won!"


    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.x < self.width / 3:
            self.player1.center_y = touch.y
        if touch.x > self.width - self.width / 3:
            self.player2.center_y = touch.y


class PongApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game

if __name__=='__main__':
        PongApp().run()`
```

This is the kv file just in case:

```
#:kivy 1.0.9


<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<PongPaddle>:
    size: 25, 200
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    player1: player_left
    player2: player_right
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player1.score)
        color: (255,0,255,1)
    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: str(root.player2.score)
        color: (255,0,255,1)
    Label:
        font_size: 40
        center_x: root.width * 3/4
        top: root.center_y
        text: str(root.message2)
        color: (0,255,0,1)
    Label:
        font_size: 40
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.center_y
        text: str(root.message1)
        color: (0,255,0,1)

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center


    PongPaddle:
        id: player_left
        x: root.x
        center_y: root.center_y


    PongPaddle:
        id: player_right
        x: root.width-self.width
        center_y: root.center_y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update function is called a lot of times and each time your condition is met you create another button. only to remove the last button created when you click at it...

Here is your bug:

```
if self.player2.score ==2 or self.player1.score==2:
    print 'WOO' # see how many times this is gonna be printed
    #make sure you don't get here more than once per game :)
    self.serve_ball(vel=(0, 0))
    self.btn= Button()
    self.add_widget(self.btn)
    self.btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
```